# Why isn't this statement working, i have imported the math library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use the `eval()` function in python, however I am facing issues.

I have imported the math library, still I am getting a NameError. I have also tried the `.replace()` method to fill in values of `x` and `y` but still it gives the same error.

```
import math
eval('(math.sin(x*y))',{'x':'0.1','y':'0.1'})
```

It is giving error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

Comment: why are you using eval?

Answer (score 2):

`eval('(math.sin(x*y))',{'x':'0.1','y':'0.1'})` does not work because the second argument that `eval` takes is `globals` and the third is `locals`. When you specify the `globals` the actual global variables cannot be used. Pass your arguments as `locals` instead:

```
eval('(math.sin(x*y))', None, {'x':0.1,'y':0.1})
```

Also don't use `eval` for this! It is **dangerous**!!

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `eval` is a dictionary containing the globally defined variables in the code you passed as string. But rather [read here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval) for more details, they explained it better than I ! But, it works when you omit the globals dictionary, because then, the globals of the script you are calling `eval` from are used. The solution is to either define the variables `x` and `y` directly in the script to avoid passing the globals dictionary, or add the math variable to that dictionary. They have an example on the site I linked with almost the same problem you encountered. Here is the working code with the latter solution.

```py
import math
eval('math.sin(x * y)',{'math': math, 'x':'0.1','y':'0.1'})
```